# Disable third party application's savefiledialog and save the data in a specific location in asp.net

Tags: permissions

I have third party software **AccessEnum ver1.32.** It retrieves the file permission of every user.It contains four columns

```
Path        Read     Write   Deny
```

I want to save the data in sql server database which information is showed by the application and i want to disable the application's save button because i want to give a static path and file name. How can i give static path and how to save data in database. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to disable the application's save button

Not possible unless you have access to the sources. Why don't you contact the application vendor ?